# VBscript error handling - move to a next item in a "For Each" loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, vbscript, error-handling

I have a loop that processes each file of a folder. In case a file is corrupted and can't be opened, I want to:
- Display the error message to the user
- Stop the execution of the remaining code
- Loop to the next file

The problem is, that if the file cannot be opened at the beginning of the loop, there's still a lot of code that will execute, which will throw other errors. I cannot exit the loop, since this would mean that not all of the files would get processed, and I cannot continue the execution of the code. Please see the part of the code below.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For each objFile in fso.GetFolder(".").Files
    If lCase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = srcExtName Then
        Set app = GetNewAppInstance (Program)
        Set fileHandle = GetNewFileHandler(app)

        On Error Resume Next
            Set objOpenFile = fileHandle.Open(objFile.path)
            If err.number <> 0 Then 
            next
                MsgBox "The file " & objFile.name & " cannot be opened. Please verify that the file is not corrupted or locked." & vbNewLine & "The file will be skipped."
                Set fileHandle = nothing : app.Quit : Set app = nothing
                <<< How can I jump to the next file from here ? >>>
            End If
        On error goto 0
        strSrcPath = fso.BuildPath(objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "._temp")
        objOpenFile.SaveAs strSrcPath, tmpExtNum
        objOpenFile.Close

        Set objOpenFile = nothing 
        Set fileHandle = nothing 
        app.Quit : Set app = nothing

        Set app = GetNewAppInstance (Program)
        Set fileHandle = GetNewFileHandler(app)

        Set objOpenFile = fileHandle.Open(strSrcPath)
        strTgtPath = fso.BuildPath(objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "." & srcExtName)
        objOpenFile.SaveAs strTgtPath, srcExtNum
        objOpenFile.Close
        fso.DeleteFile(strSrcPath)

        Set objOpenFile = nothing 
        Set fileHandle = nothing 
        app.Quit : Set app = nothing
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For each objFile in fso.GetFolder(".").Files
    If lCase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = srcExtName Then
        Set app = GetNewAppInstance (Program)
        Set fileHandle = GetNewFileHandler(app)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objOpenFile = fileHandle.Open(objFile.path)
        If err.number <> 0 Then 
            MsgBox "The file " & objFile.name & " cannot be opened. Please verify that the file is not corrupted or locked." & vbNewLine & "The file will be skipped."
            Set fileHandle = nothing : app.Quit : Set app = nothing
        Else
            strSrcPath = fso.BuildPath(objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "._temp")
            objOpenFile.SaveAs strSrcPath, tmpExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close

            Set objOpenFile = nothing 
            Set fileHandle = nothing 
            app.Quit : Set app = nothing

            Set app = GetNewAppInstance (Program)
            Set fileHandle = GetNewFileHandler(app)

            Set objOpenFile = fileHandle.Open(strSrcPath)
            strTgtPath = fso.BuildPath(objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "." & srcExtName)
            objOpenFile.SaveAs strTgtPath, srcExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close
            fso.DeleteFile(strSrcPath)

            Set objOpenFile = nothing 
            Set fileHandle = nothing 
            app.Quit : Set app = nothing               
        End If
        On error goto 0
    End If
Next
```

I've moved the "rest" of your code into the else block of your if statement, so it will only execute if you have no error.

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No prob.  Glad I could help :)